# How can the character set for popup menus be controlled in xterm

Tags: language, xterm, character-set

Somewhere along the way I've changed a setting that has caused the popup windows in xterm to be displayed in Greek characters.  The text in the main window is fine, its just the popup windows that are in Greek.  How can I change back to using English characters in the popups?

Comment: Thomas, Thanks for your response. :)  Sorry to say I'm not xterm-literate so I'm not clear on how to try what you have mentioned.

I'm running on linux and the output of the "locale" command is this :

LANG=C
LC_CTYPE="C"
LC_NUMERIC="C"
LC_TIME="C"
LC_COLLATE="C"
LC_MONETARY="C"
LC_MESSAGES="C"
LC_PAPER="C"
LC_NAME="C"
LC_ADDRESS="C"
LC_TELEPHONE="C"
LC_MEASUREMENT="C"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="C"
LC_ALL=

Comment: Here's the output from xrdb -query:
$ xrdb -query
Scrollbar.JumpCursor:   True
XTerm.VT100.geometry:   120x30
XTerm*background:       blue
XTerm*foreground:       yellow
xterm*loginShell:       true
xterm*faceName: Courrier
XTerm*geometry: 120x60-0+0
XTerm*font:     -adobe-symbol-medium-r-normal--10-100-75-75-p-61-adobe-fontspecific

Comment: Here's the output from xrdb -query:

Scrollbar.JumpCursor:   True
XTerm.VT100.geometry:   120x30
XTerm*background:       blue
XTerm*foreground:       yellow
xterm*loginShell:       true
xterm*faceName: Courrier
XTerm*geometry: 120x60-0+0
XTerm*font:     -adobe-symbol-medium-r-normal--10-100-75-75-p-61-adobe-fontspecific

Nothing stuck out to me.  Did find one thing that may be a clue.
Running as "xterm -class UXTerm" does not have the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It should "just work", since this is not a new problem (see xterm FAQ *[The first popup menu is very slow](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/xterm.faq.html#slow_menus)*).  xterm has a resource setting which tells it what the *locale* should be when initializing the menus:

> [**`menuLocale`** (class **`MenuLocale`**)](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/manpage/xterm.html#Application-Resources:menuLocale)
>                 Specify the locale used for character-set computations when
>                  loading the popup menus.  Use this to improve initialization
>                  performance of the Athena popup menus, which may load
>                  unnecessary (and very large) fonts, e.g., in a locale having
>                  UTF-8 encoding.  The default is **"C"** (POSIX).
>
> To use the current locale (only useful if you have localized
>                  the resource settings for the menu entries), set the resource
>                  to an empty string.

Possibly some packager overrode that, or there is some obscure configuration issue to be resolved.

If you're using the POSIX ("C") locale, then it does not seem likely that the X library would search for other fonts.  But if you have some resource-setting for fonts (seen with [`appres XTerm`](ftp://www.x.org/pub/X11R7.5/doc/man/man1/appres.1.html), or [`xrdb -query`](ftp://www.x.org/pub/X11R7.5/doc/man/man1/xrdb.1.html)), then that could be the source of the problem.  I suppose it is also possible to have some mis-encoded font (but that seems unlikely).